# Is it a good practice for a function sometimes return a value sometimes not

Tags: javascript

```
function Foo(p)
{
    if(!check(p))
    {
      return false;
    }
    //do something
}
```

If above code is acceptable? Because `Foo()` sometimes will return false, but most time no value return. 
If this isn't a good code, what's good?

Comment: Depends on how you calling `Foo()`.

Comment: a function by default returns undefined if no explicit return is specified.

Comment: Might be better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sometimes your function returns a value, and sometimes it returns undefined, then it will come down to how you capture what it returns, a type mismatch could halt your code.

If you just call your function like so

```
Foo(thisvalue);
```

then there will be no problems; however, if you call your function

```
var thisvariable = Foo(thisvalue);
```

then you need to be careful with how you try to use thisvariable.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in javascript will always return some value. If you don't specify it it returns `undefined`. I think it is acceptable as long as you specify this behavior. Note that in your case, it is not a good idea to return `false` since you won't be able to distinguish it easily from `undefined` (you have to use `===` comparison)

Comment: undefined can be checked like : if(typeof(yourVariableName) == "undefined") { // do this  }

Comment: it can also be checked like `if(yourVariableName === undefined)` if the variable exists (for example, if you assigned it from the return value of a function)